# How to remove data validation from selected cells in python using openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am opening a template file using openpyxl, which has data validation down to row 500 in about 5 columns.  In my python script I am loading data into the left half of the spreadsheet from Oracle, with the data validation columns being on the right.

If the data is only 50 rows I am inserting, I need to get rid of the 450 rows worth of data validation entries and formulas.  But it seems impossible to just delete a validation rule from a specific cell in openpyxl.

It seems I may have to forget about having a template with data validation already in up to rows 500, and create the validation rules manually, which I was hoping to avoid.  Much easier to have a template pre-populated, and just delete what I don't need.

This below doesn't work, as the "validation.sqref" is like "M2:500" (as this is where the validation rule is present) and so never matches the cell reference of the cell in the current iteration.

```
for row in range(start_row_to_delete, ws_data.max_row + 1):
    for col in range(1, ws_data.max_column + 1):
        cell = ws_data.cell(row=row, column=col)
            if ws_data.data_validations:
                for validation in ws_data.data_validations.dataValidation:
                    if validation.sqref == cell.coordinate:
                        ws_data.data_validations.remove(validation)
```

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation, tests or source of DataValidation objects?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues with the way you're going about this and implementing the code.
The main issue I see however makes your method obsolete anyway I think and is a waste of time.
Openpyxl DataValidation does not have a remove option so the line `ws_data.data_validations.remove(validation)` if it was ever executed would error, there is no method `.remove()`.
Also even if this line did execute, 'validation' is the whole range for that DV set in the sheet so removing 'validation' means the complete DV set would be removed from the Sheet.

There isn't any means to remove DV from an individual cell like this, therefore the only workable option would seem to be to remove the DV set and re-apply again only to the range required.
However even this is likely inefficient. If using Python to import the data to the sheet it would seem more effective to also then add necessary DV to the required columns at the same time.
You mention creating the DV manually... but is there something stopping you from applying the DV using Openpyxl (or another python module)?

If it is absolutely necessary to apply the DV in the template so that you do have these 450 rows of DV to remove, in my opinion the better option is to simply delete the rows 51 - 500. 
If taking this route then you should delete the rows in reverse, i.e. start at row 500 then delete 499, 498 etc to the last used row (.max_row) in the sheet.

**Other Options**
Data validation does have a 'Clear All' option which another module like Xlwings or Win32com could implement. Would either of these modules be usable? Both do require Excel and Windows though Xlwings should be able to do this on MACOS as well. Even if you are mainly using Openpyxl for the rest of the work using another module, if possible, is still going to be easier if the other suggestions cannot work and the only other option is manually (re-)adding the DV.

**Code Comments**
These comments are irrelevant given the restrictions of your implementation as outlined above, but if you are interested to know.

Regarding the specific issue mentioned in your code
*This below doesn't work, as the "validation.sqref" is like "M2:500" (as this is where the validation rule is present) and so never matches the cell reference of the cell in the current iteration.*

You could create a one time list of the ranges for DV prior to the loop like;

```
dv_cell_range = []
for dv in ws_data.data_validations.dataValidation:
    dv_cell_range.append(list(dv.cells.ranges)[0])
```

then in the removal loop have the test for the cell

```
            for dv_range in dv_cell_range:
                if cell.coordinate in dv_range:
```

This would check the existence of an individual cell co-ordinate in the different DV ranges, e.g. "M2:M500", "N2:N500" etc one after the other.
DV ranges however can be non-contiguous, even if the cells themselves are contiguous (depends on how DV was implemented). For example the range for a DV set could be "M2:M500 N2 N3 N4 O2:O500" so even this method would need tweaking to pick out all the ranges if this was the case.

Also note that `.max_row` and `.max_column` do not take DV sets into consideration. These values are based on the dimensions of the 'used 'cells in the sheet. While this may be OK for your columns as Headers may give you an accurate count of those across the Sheet, it's probably not going to return the value you want for the max rows. In your scenario `.max_row` should return 50 but it seems you expect it to be 500.